# How can I use project reference with difference tsconfig files?

Tags: node.js, typescript, commonjs, project-reference

For example I have three projects

```
shared
frontend
backend
```

I want to use `shared` project as project reference in the `frontend` and the `backend`

But the `backend` use `commonjs` modules and frontend use `esnext` modules, so I want `shared` to have two configs `tsconfig.commonjs.json` and `tsconfig.esmodules.json`

How can I use `shared` as reference project in the `backend` with `tsconfig.commonjs.json` and in the frontend with `tsconfig.commonjs.json`

Answer (score 0):

I believe [extends](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#extends) option is what you're looking for.

```json
// tsconfig.shared.json
  "compilerOptions": {
     ...
  }
...
```

```json
// tsconfig.frontend.json
  "extends": "./tsconfig.shared",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
  }
```

```json
// tsconfig.backend.json
  "extends": "./tsconfig.shared",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
  }
```

Comment: With such configuration when I use `shared` as referenceproject it is compiled with one config  tsconfig.shared.json